# REVIT : how to zoomtoFit a view when opening it

Tags: view, zooming, revit-api

for our addin, I need a sample of code to zoomtofit a view when opening it

I want zoom when opening and never when activating only it (by switching the activeview with revit for example)

I need to use RequestViewChange to open the view

Can you help me ?

thanks in advance

Luc

Answer (score 0):

The `UIDocument` class provides [several overloads of the `ShowElements` method](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/52ac2a55-1397-3d05-311f-de3443421ae6.htm) that can be use to achieve what you want. You can [search for `ShowElements` on The Building Coder](https://www.google.com/search?q=ShowElements&as_sitesearch=thebuildingcoder.typepad.com) and elsewhere to see numerous samples of using it.